# Qt c++ embedded mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, embedded-database

I've been writing a program on QT 5.0.2 with mingw 4.7 on windows with mysql server 5.7.

I first started with installing the MYQSL driver for QT with [this tutorial](http://www.seppemagiels.com/blog/create-mysql-driver-qt5-windows). It works and I can access the data, but i have to start the server from mysql workbench or it won't make a connection with the database (because it's not running).

For my program I need the server to start up when I run the program. This is the part where i'm stuck. I know I need to use the [libmysqld library](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/libmysqld.html) but I don't seem to get it to work. I didn't find much useful examples so i tried it like this:

this is the .pro file:

```
QT       += core sql
QT       += sql

QT       -= gui

TARGET = Temp
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\include"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib"

LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib" -llibmysqld
```

this is my main file:

```
#include <QtSQL>
#include <qsql_mysql.h>
#include <mysql.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        QSqlDatabase mydb;
        MYSQL *mysql;

        static char *server_options[] = \
        { "mysql_test", "--defaults-file=/home/cquiros/temp/mysql/my.cnf", NULL };
        int num_elements = (sizeof(server_options) / sizeof(char *)) - 1;

        static char *server_groups[] = { "embedded", NULL };

        qDebug() << "Loading embedded";
        mysql_library_init(num_elements, server_options, server_groups);
        mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
        mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, "embedded");
        mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_OPT_USE_EMBEDDED_CONNECTION, NULL);

        mysql_real_connect(mysql, NULL,NULL,NULL, "database1", 0,NULL,0);

        QMYSQLDriver *drv = new QMYSQLDriver(mysql);

        mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(drv,"connection1"); //Add the database connector to MySQL

        mydb.setDatabaseName("test");

        if (!mydb.open()) //Try to opens the database
        {
            qDebug() << "Error while opening the database";
        }
}
```

When i run this, i get this error: "

> error: undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN12QMYSQLDriverC1EP8st_mysqlP7QObject'
>   collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Can anyone help me get on track?