# C++ qt embedded mysql server

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, mingw

I'm using QT 5 with MingW 4.7 and i'm trying to start a program with an embedded mysql server.

My current program uses a mysql server, but the server has to be manually started (so out of the program). This isn't user friendly of-course.

I did some research and I need to use the [libmysqld library](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/sql-driver.html#embedded-mysql-server) . But I don't know how.

Can anyone give me an example how to use this?

Comment: Install mysql as windows service. And you can use windows API to start/monitor the mysql service. APIs: OpenSCManager OpenService QueryServiceStatusEx StartService ...

Comment: You can also try sqlite instead of mysql.

Comment: Why not use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) instead? Qt even has bindings for it, see [QSqlDatabase](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqldatabase.html).

Comment: I was requested to use Mysql or PostgreSQL!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an embedded mysql server within Qt. There are no that many difficulties with that at all. If you could point any you faced I can help you with that, indeed you should link your application with libmysqld and then just start a mysql process within your application (there are plenty documentation available about that). But as was pointed in comments - are you sure you want to do that. There are many nicer embedded solutions available like SQLLite (included in Qt)...

[Documentation and examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/libmysqld-example.html)

You probably will need to have a look on mysql driver supplied with Qt and may be fork it for embedded version, but that needs a bit closer look. But again I don't see really issues with that

Comment: I was requested to use MySQL or PostGreSQL that's why I didn't use SQLLite! I've asked a more detailed question about it a few months ago  but no one answered! Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990142/qt-c-embedded-mysql)